# NextJs-MaterialUI: Can't resolve 'react'

Tags: material-ui, next.js

I have a project and in this project I try to use Nextjs and I try to use it with Material UI in order to make it easier for me to design the interfaces.

I have the Next js app and in this app I try to use the Material UI and in the component shown below this component creates an app bar but I get this error:

```
error - ../node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-cbed451f.browser.esm.js:1:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react'
```

How can i solve the problem?

This component was imported from the material UI, and through it, an app bar is created

AppBar.js:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { styled, alpha } from "@mui/material/styles";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import InputBase from "@mui/material/InputBase";
import Badge from "@mui/material/Badge";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import Menu from "@mui/material/Menu";
import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";
import AccountCircle from "@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle";
import MailIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Mail";
import NotificationsIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Notifications";
import MoreIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoreVert";

const Search = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  position: "relative",
  borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
  backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.25),
  },
  marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  marginLeft: 0,
  width: "100%",
  [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(3),
    width: "auto",
  },
}));

const SearchIconWrapper = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 2),
  height: "100%",
  position: "absolute",
  pointerEvents: "none",
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
}));

const StyledInputBase = styled(InputBase)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: "inherit",
  "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0),
    // vertical padding + font size from searchIcon
    paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(4)})`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width"),
    width: "100%",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
      width: "20ch",
    },
  },
}));

export default function Navbar() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const [mobileMoreAnchorEl, setMobileMoreAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const isMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const isMobileMenuOpen = Boolean(mobileMoreAnchorEl);

  const handleProfileMenuOpen = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleMobileMenuClose = () => {
    setMobileMoreAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const handleMenuClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    handleMobileMenuClose();
  };

  const handleMobileMenuOpen = (event) => {
    setMobileMoreAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const menuId = "primary-search-account-menu";
  const renderMenu = (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={anchorEl}
      anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: "top",
        horizontal: "right",
      }}
      id={menuId}
      keepMounted
      transformOrigin={{
        vertical: "top",
        horizontal: "right",
      }}
      open={isMenuOpen}
      onClose={handleMenuClose}
    >
      <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>My account</MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  );

  const mobileMenuId = "primary-search-account-menu-mobile";
  const renderMobileMenu = (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={mobileMoreAnchorEl}
      anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: "top",
        horizontal: "right",
      }}
      id={mobileMenuId}
      keepMounted
      transformOrigin={{
        vertical: "top",
        horizontal: "right",
      }}
      open={isMobileMenuOpen}
      onClose={handleMobileMenuClose}
    >
      <MenuItem>
        <IconButton size="large" aria-label="show 4 new mails" color="inherit">
          <Badge badgeContent={4} color="error">
            <MailIcon />
          </Badge>
        </IconButton>
        <p>Messages</p>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>
        <IconButton
          size="large"
          aria-label="show 17 new notifications"
          color="inherit"
        >
          <Badge badgeContent={17} color="error">
            <NotificationsIcon />
          </Badge>
        </IconButton>
        <p>Notifications</p>
      </MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}>
        <IconButton
          size="large"
          aria-label="account of current user"
          aria-controls="primary-search-account-menu"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          color="inherit"
        >
          <AccountCircle />
        </IconButton>
        <p>Profile</p>
      </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  );

  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            size="large"
            edge="start"
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            sx={{ mr: 2 }}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            noWrap
            component="div"
            sx={{ display: { xs: "none", sm: "block" } }}
          >
            MUI
          </Typography>
          <Search>
            <SearchIconWrapper>
              <SearchIcon />
            </SearchIconWrapper>
            <StyledInputBase
              placeholder="Search…"
              inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search" }}
            />
          </Search>
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} />
          <Box sx={{ display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" } }}>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="show 4 new mails"
              color="inherit"
            >
              <Badge badgeContent={4} color="error">
                <MailIcon />
              </Badge>
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="show 17 new notifications"
              color="inherit"
            >
              <Badge badgeContent={17} color="error">
                <NotificationsIcon />
              </Badge>
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              edge="end"
              aria-label="account of current user"
              aria-controls={menuId}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <AccountCircle />
            </IconButton>
          </Box>
          <Box sx={{ display: { xs: "flex", md: "none" } }}>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="show more"
              aria-controls={mobileMenuId}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleMobileMenuOpen}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <MoreIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      {renderMobileMenu}
      {renderMenu}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, in order to use the material UI with the Nextjs, several steps must be taken:

1. You have to go to the next link:

   https://github.com/vercel/next.js/
2. After entering the link, you must go to the following folder:

   /examples
3. After going to example folder, you must search for the folder "with-material-ui" and then enter the folder.
4. Then go to the link in the "with-material-ui" folder:

   mui/material-ui
5. After entering the link "mui/material-ui", go to the following folder:

   /pages
6. Then copy the "_app.js" file and the "document.js" file to your project.
7. Then go back to the folder "next.js" and then go to the folder "src" and copy the file "createEmotionCache.js" and the file "theme.js" to your src project.

Note that you must go to the "Installation" section of the documentation for Material UI and install the following packages:

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
npm install @mui/icons-material
```